# Use Angular Element in app.component.html

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements, micro-frontend

I have been playing with Angular Elements for a while. Our team is building multiple independent angular projects and convert them into Angular Elements. We also build a main shell and those angular elements will be called in the main shell.

The main shell is written by Angular. So far I found I only can embed the angular elements into `index.html` in main shell. However, I wonder is there a way to use the angular elements in `app.component.html`?

**index.html in mainShell**: it's working fine using `app1-element` here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  ...
    <script src="../../elements/app1-element.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app1-element></app1-element> 
  </body>
</html>
```

The angular projects structure is shown below. So how to use `app1-element` in `app.component.html`? I use the similar code there and it doesn't work. By the way, to run the main shell, I use `Go Live` from `mainShell/src`

```
app1
--src
----app
------app.module.ts (customElements.define('app1-element', el);)
--package.json

mainShell
--src
----app
------app.component.html (I want to use 'app1-element' here)
----index.html
--package.json
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I figured out. To use Angular element in `app.component.html`, you need to import the `.js` file properly. There are a couple of ways to do it, you can use SystemJS, dimport, or static import by using JQuery. I my demo, I import the `.js` file static, plz refer to this article [here](https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular)